# write arrays to

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

this is part of a MFC project. It crashes. 
1. I am trying to write array of arrays to binary files as fast as I can. I used different ways to avoid the crash such EnterCriticalSection , etc. It failed to work.
This is an example of larger project. I am trying to practice the feasibility of such approach.

```
char filename[200];
UINT ThreadProc( LPVOID Param );
int *BUF[10];
int count = 0;
void CThreadDlg::OnOK() 
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
     {
            BUF[i] = new int [500];
            for (int j = 0; j < 500; ++j)
            {
                BUF[i][j] = i + j;
            }



            AfxBeginThread(ThreadProc,NULL,THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,0,NULL);
            count  = count + 1;

     }



     for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
     {
        delete [] BUF[i];
        BUF[i] = NULL;
     }

}


UINT ThreadProc( LPVOID Param )
{
    sprintf_s(filename, "C:\\Temp\\test%d.bin", count);
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open(filename, std::ios::out);
    file.write((char *)BUF[count], 4*500);
    file.close();
    file.clear();

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably simplest to read chunks (either using `BinaryReader.Read(byte[], int, int)` or `BinaryReader.ReadBytes(int)`) and then use `Buffer.BlockCopy` to efficiently convert from bytes to floats etc. Note that this will be endian-sensitive, however. If you want to convert more robustly (so that you can change endianness later, or run on a big-endian platform) you'd probably want to call `ReadFloat()` repeatedly.

Comment: May be you are misunderstanding my question. I am trying to write 10 buffers to 10 different files using threads. arrays are of type Int.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't have any thread synchronization. You dynamically allocate 10 different buffers (of 500 elements), and start 10 different threads. You *logically* assign `Nth` buffer to `Nth` thread. But you don't synchronize the `count` variable. Consider it:

- From `OnOK`, assume `count` is 3. You allocate buffer for it and start thread. You do **assume** `count = 3` will be received by this new thread. But you are grossly wrong. Value of `count` may be 3..10 when the thread actually starts (I mean 4th thread, for `count=3`, ignore the previously started threads). You may make duplicate file name, since same `count` may be processed by more than one thread.
- As soon as you start all threads, you immediately delete the allocated buffer! Do you know that threads may or may not have started/finished processing? How can you delete the entire set of buffers, without letting threads to process them? Bang! A Crash!

Instead of using global variables `BUF` and `count` for this kind of thread sync/data-passing. Just allocate buffer (within for-loop), and send the buffer using the `thread-param` parameter (the `LPVOID` argument). Receive the same buffer within the thread, typecast it, use it, write and and then delete it *from* the thread itself. Don't delete the buffer from `OnOK`.

Sample code:

```
int* pBuffer = new int [500];
// Assign different values to `pBuffer`, and then...
AfxBeginThread(ThreadProc,pBuffer);
```

In thread:

```
UINT ThreadProc( LPVOID Param )
{
   int* pTheBuffer = (int*)Param;
   ...
}
```

You may want to read: [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43994/The-Practical-Guide-to-Multithreading-Part-1), or [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65158/The-Practical-Guide-to-Multithreading-Part-2).

Comment: can you expand your suggestion and show how to pass both the buffer and the count or the file name to the ThreadProc?. you are passing just the buffer. Pass the buffer and the count or the file name.

Comment: Okay, in that case, just pass the file-counter. Prepare the buffer within the thread-func, use it and delete it from there.

Comment: no, have to pass both of them. maybe create a struct or a class that has both and pass it as an object to the thread?.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But you must dynamically allocate an object, and release it in thread.

Comment: this would slow the process down if I am doing this continuously for relatively large number of times. what safe options are available?.

Comment: Your thread isn't doing any lengthy or CPU intensive job. You didn't care for that, and spawned dozens of unnecessary threads. And now you are caring about data passing?